# A lot of SIGSEGV while strace'ing java process

Tags: java, segmentation-fault, strace

Interesting stuff occurred while I debug one of the unit tests on CI server (maven build actually). I connect to java process with `strace -ff -e trace=network -p [pid]` to trace network activity of build process. And that's what I saw:

```
Process 26324 attached
Process 26325 attached (waiting for parent)
Process 26325 resumed (parent 26312 ready)
Process 26325 detached
Process 26324 detached
Process 26320 detached
Process 26317 detached
Process 26308 resumed
[pid 26308] --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
Process 26307 resumed
Process 26308 detached
[pid 26310] --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
Process 26310 detached
[pid 25551] --- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
Process 26309 detached
Process 26307 detached
[pid 25717] --- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
[pid 25715] --- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
[pid 25713] --- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
[pid 25551] socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 163
[pid 25551] setsockopt(163, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, [1], 4) = 0
[pid 25551] bind(163, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(6590), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
Process 26471 attached (waiting for parent)
Process 26471 resumed (parent 25551 ready)
[pid 25551] --- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
[pid 25551] --- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
[pid 26471] recvfrom(163,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 25551] socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 164
[pid 25551] setsockopt(164, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, [1], 4) = 0
[pid 25551] bind(164, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
[pid 25551] getsockname(164, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(45728), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")},[16]) = 0
[pid 25551] --- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
[pid 26471] <... recvfrom resumed> 0x8e80618, 65536, 0, 0x6ef6aea0, 0x6ef6ae9c) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
[pid 26471] --- SIGRT_29 (Real-time signal 27) @ 0 (0) ---
Process 26471 detached
Process 26472 attached (waiting for parent)
Process 26472 resumed (parent 25551 ready)
Process 26473 attached (waiting for parent)
Process 26473 resumed (parent 25551 ready)
```

So, there we have some network activity (it's what I am actually search for), and a lot of `SIGSEGV` signals.

Build finished correctly (just one broken test). Situation determinable and reproduced over and over again. What does this mean?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since this is java, it means that your JVM is using SIGSEGVs for something.  Common uses include

- null pointer dereferences -- the JVM catches SIGSEGVs to address 0 and turns them into NullPointerExceptions
- garbage collection write barriers -- rarely changed pages are marked read only and SEGVs catch writes to them.  This way the garbage collector doesn't have to rescan all of memory all of the time.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! Can you provide some links where I can find more information about this stuff?

Comment: Is this harmless then or should it be addressed? I am seeing similar occuring on my application running on solaris via truss.

Comment: I think there is no need to be worried :)

Comment: Second point is very dangerous when you do JNI and that part blocks all signals (respectively SIGSEGV). Application will then encounter seamingly random SIGSEGV-triggered crashes (looking like race conditions or invalid memory access) that are very difficult to trace down.

Comment: Given a line like this from an strace of a JVM: "--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---" is it safe to assume that's a Null Pointer Exception because of those zeros?

Comment: @spl: if the program seems to run fine, then yes, those SIGSEGVs are actually NullPointerExceptions