# Ubuntu Segmentation Fault running Bitwig Studio

Tags: ubuntu, segmentation-fault

I make with music Bitwig Studio (third-party). It crashed and I selected "Leave Closed". Now it won't open. I've uninstalled using apt, removed and purged using dpkg, reinstalled a fresh copy from bitwig.com. Nothing works.

Here is the gdb output

```
Starting program: /usr/bin/bitwig-studio 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-
gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
process 11197 is executing new program: /opt/bitwig-studio/bitwig-
studio
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-
gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
JRE Path: //opt/bitwig-studio/lib/jre

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffe603e2b4 in ?? ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007fffe603e2b4 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000246 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007fffe603e160 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007ffff6e78990 in VM_Operation::_names ()
   from //opt/bitwig-studio/lib/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fffffffa400 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007ffff69a868d in VM_Version::get_processor_features() ()
   from //opt/bitwig-studio/lib/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) quit
```

Answer (score 0):

> `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.`

The stack trace you get is

1. Completely useless, and
2. Is unlikely to have anything to do with your actual problem (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20233065/50617)).

To solve your actual problem, you would likely need to contact [support @bitwig.com](https://www.bitwig.com/en/support/faq.html).